# Using IEEE Citation style, how should I Cite a Figure, that was based on one in a text?

Tags: citations, graphics

In a lecture I watched,
I found a very good diagram that explains a concept I am trying to explain.
I couldn't get hold of the original image, so I recreated it in Tikz -- with a few changes to make it perfect for what I am doing.

This lecture is not a primary source for the concept explained in the diagram -- it uses ideas from other papers I am citing. Though I do cite it a few times, where the ideas it explained were clearer than the base texts (as well as citing the base texts).

In the caption should I put:

> ... , then generating all the layers below. Right: A DNN initialized using the DBN [1].

Or

> ...  then generating all the layers below. Right: A DNN initialized using the DBN. This diagram based on one found in [1].

Or even -- since the caption is also drawing heavily on the lecture

> ...  then generating all the layers below. Right: A DNN initialized using the DBN[1]. This diagram based on one found in [1].

Where [1] is the index in my bibliography for the lecture.

---

**Related:** [Creating a schematic figure based on an existing one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16571/creating-a-schematic-figure-based-on-an-existing-one)

Comment: I am interested to know what the -1 was about. (Not too concerned though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way folks in my neck of the woods handle this would be to say "... A DNN initialized using the DBN (adapted from [1])."