# How and where should images be cited?

Tags: citation-style

I am currently working on a paper where we use one image from another paper. How and where should I denote that?

Currently, we have the image source only in the caption like this:

```
\caption{Comparison of a \gls{CNN} for classification (top)
         and a \gls{FCN} which creates a heat map (bottom).
         \cite{long2014fully}}
```

Comment: See also: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19845/using-ieee-citation-style-how-should-i-cite-a-figure-that-was-based-on-one-in

Comment: This is certainly not correct; the citation has to be a part of a sentence. It really depends on what you cite -- the image itself (i.e., you "printscreen" it) which may be a copyright infringement, or the data used in the image?

Comment: I should note that it is exactly the same figure in my case.

Comment: Well, in that case you either have the copyright holder's permission (and then you probably just say something like `image taken from \cite{abc}` or you violate the copyright and in that case you ... well ... shouldn't do it.

Comment: @yo' citation does not have to be part of a sentence. In that case putting it after the punctuation is correct for most footnote citation styles. Really, this serves to indicate though, this question can not be answered without reference for the Style Manual (or at least the venue) for what ever document is being produced.

Comment: @Oxinabox You believe that most venues have strict style manuals? In my life, I have rarely seen any style manuals.

Comment: @yo' They do not, that's why I said "or at least the venue". If moose told us the venue, then someone could answer by knowing the "unwritten rules".
Trust me I have been digging through ACM SIG rules today. Bits are in the style guide, bits are in the FAQ, bits are in the TEX class comments, bits are in the examples. But a lot I had to check by reading papers from the conference last year... and they were not entirely consistent.
My point being we need something to work from. It is hard enough when you know the venue.

Comment: This is part of a university course. It's called a "Seminar" in German. I have no idea how that would be translated into English / if this is common in English speaking countries at all. The document will quite sure not be published. The purpose of a "Seminar" is to get knowledge about a new topic and exchange the knowledge between the students who participate in it.

Comment: @Oxinabox Most venues do not list style manuals because they do not care enough, meaning you should do as you wish. The worst thing that can happen is that they correct you or ask for a correction.

Comment: @moose: You should clarify it is not for publication, it has implications.

Comment: Also see [I'd like to use a figure from a paper, what's the best way to do this?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3100/id-like-to-use-a-figure-from-a-paper-whats-the-best-way-to-do-this)

Answer (score 1):

The right thing to do when plan to include an image from another article is to first ask for the permission from the corresponding author of the article. If approved, you may include the image and cite them along with the lines after the caption

> Included with permission from [citeno].

General citation would only allow you to *refer* information in literature. Any form of replication whether it is an image or even a set of sentences of text is not permitted without acknowledgement from the authors of the published material to be referred. The exception is for quotes and equations (with appropriate citations). That doesn't forbid you to use the text at all. It means that you ought to rephrase the information referred in you own words.

Comment: *Any form of replication whether it is an image or even a sentence of text is not permitted without acknowledgement from the authors of the published material to be referred.* - You're talking about copyright law here, aren't you? I guess at least for texts the situation is different in Germany. Parts of a text may be copied, as long as it's clear which parts got copied and as long as the copying is not "too much" (see [§51 UrhG](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/urhg/__51.html))

Comment: Suggestion accepted. Edit made. But on copyright, all materials published are implicitly copyrighted even if not formally done so.

Comment: This is plain wrong. Very rarely it is the corresponding author who holds the image copyright. More likely it is the publisher. We were solving this issue with one guy in my community, and we ended up with him giving me the plot data and not the image, to avoid this issue.

Comment: Actually not all publishers hold copyrights for the images like IEEE.