# When Does "Adapting" An Image Go Too Far?

Tags: copyright, graphics

I am interested in using a particular figure from the literature, but I do not want to go through the hassle of paying to use a figure. What I am wondering is if I made a similar figure, how easy is it to get in trouble for copyright infringement? If I were to essentially redo the image, it would not be verbatim the same, but very similar depictions would be pulled from the image. As an example, I provided two illustrative examples where the bottom image is an "adapted" version:

The second one is in a published paper as well from a reputable journal, so I am guessing that it should be okay to go about making a similar diagram myself, but again, I wouldn't mind other opinions as too when I might start to tow the line on copyright infringement.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe this would fit the Law StackExchange more. Not sure if it’s off-topic for this site, though.

Comment: Are you sure you must pay? If it is for a paper or didactical use probably you just have to ask a permission or just properly cite the reference, respectively.

Comment: Is this for inclusion in a book or a paper?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much do figures need to differ to avoid copyright claims?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/4881/how-much-do-figures-need-to-differ-to-avoid-copyright-claims) The two figures you give examples of share the same *information*, which cannot be copyrighted (but must be cited), but they differ substantially in design.

Comment: @BryanKrause, actually, I see not very much difference in design. In fact it looks like an attempt to mislead about the source.

Comment: "I do not want to go through the hassle of paying to use a figure": Have you already asked permissions to reuse? In my experience, many people have a distorted view on this: for many types of publications (e.g. papers in other publisher's journals, dissertations, books), publishers don't charge anything to republish a figure, they just ask one to put a certain notice. That's it. Ask first!

Comment: To be fair to the author of the "adapted" image on the bottom - they do explicitly make reference that they've adapted it from another author. The authors of the bottom image do not claim to have come up with it on their own. @Massimo Ortolano I will probably go ahead and follow up on your suggestion, I guess the worst thing they can do is say no.

Comment: Do you want to avoid the "hassle" of paying for a figure, or do you not want to *pay* for the figure?

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a book, rather than for a paper, you have another option. Many book publishers will give you a certain budget for paying royalties on figures and such. Another alternative, if you are to receive royalties from book sales is to have the publisher pay any fees up front and charge it against your future earnings on the book. The former is preferable, of course. But book publishers expect to have to pay for some things such as cover pictures and some internal figures.

I doubt that this is an option for any journal, however.

Answer (score -6):

If you do the image you then have no problem and under the image description you use :'fuente propia' (self source/made). if you want to use a figure from a magazine/paper/site/etc, then you simply  add the proper source and citing in your references. Remember that the difference between plagiarism and fair use is merely citation.

**Clarification:**

As long as it is cited and properly explained it's a problem, although it would be wise to check the local legislation because it varies from country to country. In my country the law specifies 'copy or reproduction'of the exact same thing, but redoing a new image/chart is no problem.

If its different for your countries then add a comment of what exactly the law in your places say to contribute to responding OPs question.

Comment: This is absolutely wrong.  Citing an image that you boost does not make it fair use, and using it in a publication is most certainly a copyright violation.

Comment: @Scott Seidman as long as it is cited and properly explained it's a problem, although it would be wise to check the local legislation because it varies from country to country. In my country the law specifies 'copy or reproduction' but redoing a new image/chart is no problem. What does law in your place say?

Comment: I stand corrected.  My statement is only true if the use is in one of the 177 countries on the list shown at https://copyrighthouse.co.uk/copyright/countries-berne-convention.htm, which are all signatories of the Berne Convention, a treaty that states that a copyright issued in signatory states is valid in signatory states.

Comment: @Scott Seidman that also means that there are still countries which are not included . Take your pick, FIFA lists 211 existing countries, ISOs 249, Olympics 206 . At worst it means there are 72 countries with different regulations, not to mention that copyright does not protect ' idea, procedure, process, system, method of operation, concept, principle, or discovery, regardless of the form in which it is described, explained, illustrated, or embodied in such work' https://copyrighthouse.co.uk/copyright/what-copyright-doesnt-protect.htm  , if OP is makign the diagram of an idea it's still fair.

Comment: This is a bad, bad idea. In academic writing you're not doing well if "it's only wrong in most developed countries".

Comment: @ObscureOwl It should work completely or it doesnt work, and a good DIY on images is perfectly normal. You can make your own Maslow pyramid graph and as long as you explain based on Maslow's pyramid is perfectly fine and normal.